# HTML Canvas: drawImage with 2x2 tile on an isometric map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, isometric

Hi I am trying to draw images on an isometric map within HTML canvas element.

I can do that without problems using one tile to render an image on the isometric map.
However, I would also like to draw images which use 2x2 tiles (so twice bigger than the normal ones described above) like this.
(1x1 presents one image on one tile while 2x2 indicates rendering one image on 2x2(4) tiles. Although the image looks fine, but it just renders 4 images on 4 tiles [= one image on one tile])
[image]

I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245843/html5-isometric-with-big-objects/9797860#9797860), but it doesn't really solve the problem.
I also tried just make the image size bigger but it didn't work properly.

Could anyone please help me to achieve rendering an image on 2x2 tile on the isometric map?

You can see the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dawn-gf7et9?file=/src/App.tsx) on sandbox

And entire code is [here](https://github.com/masafumimori/Isometric-map) on GitHub